# How to search for exact phrases using the MySQL MeCab Full-Text Parser Plugin?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, cjk, mecab

I'm using MySQL 8.0.27.

```sql
MATCH (column) AGAINST ('その猫' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
MATCH (column) AGAINST ('"その猫"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Both statements show "その小さな猫" in the results.

The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search-mecab.html) says:

> For boolean mode search, the search term is converted to a search phrase.

So I would expect to not need the quoation marks, but it does not work in either case.

Comment: Not very familiar with MySQL FTS, but it looks like without the quotes it's equivalent to "その OR 猫", so it's not surprising it hits その小さな猫. The double quotes seem like they should work as expected, maybe you can combine it with a LIKE query like this suggests? https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mysql-cookbook/0596001452/ch04s15.html

Comment: Thanks! As a workaround adding `LIKE` gives the correct results.

Comment: @Steffen can you add that as an answer and accept it? Thank you!

Comment: @AhmedFasih I'm still waiting if someone knows why this isn't working properly to begin with. The workaround achieves the desired result, but it doesn't necessarily answer my question. I unfortunately already had a few cases where `MATCH` leaves too many rows and the non-sargable workaround ends up completely defeating the purpose of having an index.